# Kubernetes local port for deployment in Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm trying to expose my Deployment to a port which I can access through my local computer via Minikube.

I have tried two YAML configurations (one a load balancer, one just a service exposing a port).
I: http://pastebin.com/gL5ZBZg7

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bot
labels:
    app: bot
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: bot
```

II: http://pastebin.com/sSuyhzC5

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bot
  labels:
    app: bot
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: bot
```

The deployment and the docker container image both expose port 8000, and the Pod is tagged with app:bot.

The first results in a service with a port which never finishes, and the external IP never gets assigned.
The second results in a port of bot:8000 TCP, bot:0 TCP in my dashboard and when I try "minikube service bot" nothing happens.  The same happens if I type in "kubectl expose service bot".

I am on Mac OS X.

How can I set this up properly?

Answer (score 3):

The `LoadBalancer` service is meant for Cloud providers and not really relevant for minikube.

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-loadbalancer):

> On cloud providers which support external load balancers, setting the type field to "LoadBalancer" will provision a load balancer for your Service.

Using a `Service` of type `NodePort` (see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#type-nodeport)) as mentioned in the [Networking part of the minikube documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#networking) is the intended way of exposing services on minikube.

So your configuration should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bot
  labels:
    app: bot
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
    nodePort: 30356
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: bot
```

And access your application through:

```
> IP=$(minikube ip)
> curl "http://$IP:30356"
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Minikube now has the service command to access a service.

Use `kubectl service <myservice>`.

That will give you a URL which you can use to talk to the service.